# ¿Por qué solo funciona en el segundo envío del formulario?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, heroku

Resulta que estoy realizando un creación de usuario con *"Node.js"* y *Firebease* con el siguiente código.

Los usuarios, se registran correctamente, el problema se encuentra que luego de un rato si deseo inscribir un usuario con el mismo correo o usuario, no me indica que el usuario o correo ya se encuentra registrado y actualiza el existente, pero si seguidamente lo envío de nuevo, sí, me indica que ya se encuentra registrado. Si actualizo los archivos en el servidor de *Node* e ingreso un usuario repetido, lo actualiza, y no me indica que está repetido, pero si seguidamente envío de nuevo el registro, sí, me indica que está registrado.

Solo me indica que está registrado el mismo correo o usuario si envío el formulario 2 veces seguidas. Si lo envío, al pasar un rato, no me lo indica:

```
app.post('/SignUp', function(request, response) {

  var Email       = request.body.Email.toLowerCase();
  var User        = request.body.User.toLowerCase();
  var Pass        = request.body.Pass;
  var Nombre      = request.body.Nombre;
  var Apellido    = request.body.Apellido;
  var Genero      = request.body.Genero;
  var db          = firebase.database();
  var Tabla       = "DataUsers";
  var Resultado   = {"Resultado": "null"};
  var CompareUser = null;
  var CompareEmail = null;

  //ValidateDB (db,Tabla);
  CompareUser = CompareUsers(db, Tabla, User);
  CompareEmail = CompareEmails(db, Tabla, Email);
  var token= createToken(User);
  //var AccountValidate = validateAccount(token, TOKEN_SECRET);

  if ( !CompareUser & !CompareEmail)
  {
    process.env.TZ = 'America/Panama';
    var DateCreate = new Date();

    db.ref(Tabla).child(User).set({
      "User"      : User ,
      "Email"     : Email,
      "DateCreate": DateCreate.toString(),
      "Pass"      : Pass,
      "Nombre"    : Nombre,
      "Apellido"  : Apellido,
      "Genero"    : Genero,
      "AccountValidate"    : false,
      "TOKEN"     : token
    });

    db.ref(Tabla).child(User).once('value', function(snapshot) {
      EmailCtrl.variable(Email);
      //EmailCtrl.sendEmail();
      Resultado = {"Resultado": "UserCreate"};
    });
  }else
  if ( CompareUser ) {
    Resultado = {"Resultado": "UserDuplicate"};
  }else
  if ( CompareEmail) {
    Resultado = {"Resultado": "EmailDuplicate"};
  };
  response.send(JSON.stringify(Resultado));
});
function CompareEmails(db, Tabla, Email){

  var resultado = false;

  db.ref(Tabla).orderByChild('Email').equalTo(Email).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var email = snapshot.val();
    if (email != null){
      resultado = true;
    }
  }, function (errorObject) {
    resultado ="The read failed: " + errorObject.code;
  });
  return resultado;
};

function CompareUsers(db, Tabla, User){

  var resultado = false;
  db.ref(Tabla).orderByChild('User').equalTo(User).on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var result = snapshot.val();
    if (result != null)
    {
      resultado = true;
    };
  }, function (errorObject) {
    resultado ="The read failed: " + errorObject.code;
  });
  return resultado;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No he trabajado con ese framework, pero según la [documentación de Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/retrieve-data?hl=es), los métodos que estás utilizando son asíncronos, por tanto, deberías encadenar callbacks o trabajar con promesas. Supongo que cuando haces dos peticiones seguidas, la segunda vez que te suscribes al evento "value" se lanza el retorno de la primera petición.

La suscripción a eventos es muy útil si utilizas [Firebase desde el navegador](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=es&js=y&prev=_t&hl=es&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.airpair.com%2Ffirebase%2Fposts%2Ffirebase-building-realtime-app&edit-text=&act=url), puesto que te mantienes a la escucha de queries y actúas en consecuencia.

Answer (score 0):

porque esta usando el método set? Hace unos días, si no mal recuerdo tenia ese problema, los datos se remplazaban. Entonces cambie el método **set** por **push**.

```js
db.ref(Tabla).child(User).push({
      "User"      : User ,
      "Email"     : Email,
      "DateCreate": DateCreate.toString(),
      "Pass"      : Pass,
      "Nombre"    : Nombre,
      "Apellido"  : Apellido,
      "Genero"    : Genero,
      "AccountValidate"    : false,
      "TOKEN"     : token
    });
```